# No effects with WaitForSeconds

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want my character to stop when I press a button on my gamepad or keyboard. The character must do a specific animation when I press the button and nothing else, so no movement at all, just the animation.
I'm trying to figure out how WaitForSeconds works, but when I try to use it, it doesn't work. Here the code of the function that calls WaitForSeconds

```
public IEnumerator Wait()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds (6);
}
```

When the bool variable animationTest is true I want the program to wait for 6 seconds

```
if (animationTest) 
{
    UnityEngine.Debug.Log ("check1");
    StartCoroutine (Wait ());
    UnityEngine.Debug.Log ("check2");
    animationTest = false;
}
```

but this doesn't work! check1 and check2 are printed at the same time. I'm missing something. This runs in `FixedUpdate()`.

Comment: why dont you post at http://answers.unity3d.com ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Coroutine does not work like this. It starts a new (parallel) execution.
In order to achieve the wait you'd have to do it in the `IEnumerator`.

```
public IEnumerator SomethingElse() {
  animationTest = false;
  Debug.Log("check1");
  yield return new WaidForSeconds(6f);
  Debug.Log("check2");
  yield return true;
}

void FixedUpdate() {
  if (animationTest) {
    StartCoroutine(SomethingElse());
  }
}
```

Now when you set the `animationTest` at some point, you should see the two logs with a time gap of 6 seconds in between.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Now if I want to stop not a parallel execution, but the thread from where I launch the WaitForSeconds how can I do it?